# Kafka Messages Processing

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka distributed system for message processing in spring boot application. Now my application are producing messages on even basic to three different different topics. There is one separate spring boot application which will be used by some data analysis team who will analysis the data. This application is a simple report type application with only one filter Topic.

Now I have to implement this but I am little bit confused how I will show the data to the UI. I have written listeners (Consumers) who are consuming the messages but how I will show the data to the UI on real time basic. Should I need to store it in some database like redis and then show this data to UI? Is this the correct way to deal with consumer in Kafka? Will it not be slow? As messages can grow drastically over the time.

In nutshell I want to know to how we can show messages on any UI in the efficient way and in real time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a consumer to forward to a websocket.

Or you can use Kafka Connect to write to a database, then write a REST API

Or use Kafka Streams Interactive Queries feature + add a RPC layer on top for Javascript to call

Comment: Write to database with Kafka connect will not impact the performance when the messages count are to large?Or you are taking about some in memory database like redis etc.